# C++ segmentation fault pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

A program that I am writing takes an array of names and ages and alphabetizes them. Sometimes the program will work. Most of the time I get a segmentation fault about halfway through printing the alphabetized list.

This is a sample from my header file

```
public:

    static const int MAXSTU = 50;

    Student();

    void inputData();
    void sortData();
    void printOriginalData();
    void printAlphaData();

private:
    int arraytotal;
    int *temp1;
    std::string *temp2;

    std::string originalname[MAXSTU]; 
    std::string *alphaname[MAXSTU];
    int originalage[MAXSTU];
    int *alphaage[MAXSTU];
```

these are the functions that are causing the issues.

```
void Student::sortData() {
      for(int i=0;i < arraytotal;i++) {
          if (originalname[i] > originalname[i+1] ) {
            temp1 = alphaage[i];
            alphaage[i] = alphaage[i + 1];
            alphaage[i + 1] = temp1;
            temp2 = alphaname[i];
            alphaname[i] = alphaname[i + 1];
            alphaname[i+1]= temp2;
          }
      }
}

void Student::printAlphaData()
{
     cout << "\nAlphabetized list\n";
     cout << "---------------------------\n";

     for (int i = 0; i < arraytotal; ++i) 
     {
         cout << left << setw(30) << *alphaname[i];
         cout << right << setw(10) << *alphaage[i] << endl; 
     }
     cout << endl;
}
```

Any help with figuring out where the issue is will be appreciated. Also is there a better way to sort my array into alphabetical order?

Comment: Perhaps using `std::sort`?  And why use arrays when you can use `std::vector`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `std::string*` instead of just `std::string`?

Comment: And why are `temp1` and `temp2` class members, when they should just be locals in the method(s) where they are used?

Comment: This program is for an assigment for a C++ class. I have to use parallel name and age arrays for the data.

Comment: I dont have a specific reason for using std::string* it doesnt compile with std::string. The big problem is locating where the program has its segmentation fault. I cant figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: try to change line `for(int i=0;i < arraytotal;i++)` in function `Student::SortData()` to be `for( int i = 0; i < arraytotal - 1; i++)` ? it seems an overbuffering of the array `alphaname` and `alphaage`.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::map<std::string, int>` where `first` is the name and `second` is the age?  That'll sort it for free.

Comment: What is the value of `arraytotal`? If it is the actual size of the arrays, then the loop condition in `sortData()` should be `i < arraytotal - 1` as you are accessing the elements with index `i+1`.

Comment: Can you post a compilable/runnable sample? As it is, the only issue I can see is the `arraytotal` issue that Christoph found. (note that this won't sort properly, to do a bubble-sort you need two loops) and the problem could be caused elsewhere but only causing a problem here. (etc)